# How to pass edit an object that is part of the state and return that edited object back?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, lodash

I have one obj like so:

```
Object{}
```

This object has other objects inside of it, but are marked by keys, like so:

```
Object{1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object}
```

I want to be able to select one of those objects or edit by having only the value of the key. So lets say object 1 is an object that has

```
1: Object {
   title: "yay Im a title",
   description: "yay Im a desc",
   quantity: 1
   }
```

I want to be able to get back a value like 1 and be able to take that certain object with the key of 1 out and update the quantity by 1 each time the function or whatever is called. If this doesn't make since please let me know.

This is with a project I am working with in react/redux.

I will post each relevant code:

action:

```
 export function updateCart(_id, unit) {
  return {
    type: "UPDATE_CART",
    _id: _id,
    unit: unit
  }
}
```

reducer:

```
case "UPDATE_CART":
    let foundBook = _.get(state, action._id);
    //Stuck here, want to update quantity by one and return the item
    break;
```

component in which is calling action:

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {addToCart, updateCart} from '../../actions/cartActions';

class BookItem extends Component {

  handleCart() {
    const book = {
      _id: this.props._id,
      title: this.props.title,
      description: this.props.description,
      price: this.props.price,
      quantity: 1
    }
    if(Object.keys(this.props.cart).length > 0) {
      let _id = this.props._id;

      let cartIndex = _id in this.props.cart;
      if(!cartIndex) {
        this.props.addToCart(book);
      } else {
        this.props.updateCart(_id, 1);
      }

    } else {
      this.props.addToCart(book);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="well">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-xs-12">
            <h6>{this.props.title}</h6>
            <p>{this.props.description}</p>
            <h6>{this.props.price}</h6>
            <button onClick={this.handleCart.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary">Buy now</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 return {
   cart: state.cart
 }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {addToCart, updateCart})(BookItem);
```

Hopefully this didn't make this to confusing now, but as request I posted what I am working on to hopefully help.

Comment: Based on what do you *want to be able to get back a value like 1*? What are you going to give in order to "get back" a 1? Note that you can access a property value with a dynamic key using square brackets: `key = 1; myTitle = myObject[key].title`

Comment: I was able to get the object out of the large object by using lodash and using var foundItem = _.get(state, 1); . This returned the object that I wanted with all its properties, now I need to be able to edit that object and still return all of its old properties.

Comment: This is too vague. Please post your code, and desired outcome. BTW, you did not mention `state` in your question. Be as concrete as possible.

Comment: Updated code. Sorry for confusion

Answer (score 0):

A very basic approach might be to create a function that will take an object, key, and optional function as parameters.  If a function is provided as the third parameter it would be evaluated against the child object with the given key, if located.  The child object, if located, is returned.

The use of `hasOwnProperty` allows location of child objects that belong to the parent object alone, and not inherited from the prototype.

```
function extract(obj, key,fn) {
    if (obj === null || typeof obj !== 'object' || 
        key === null || !obj.hasOwnProperty(key) || typeof obj[key] !== 'object' || 
        obj[key] === null) 
        return null;

    if (typeof fn === 'function' && fn !== null) 
        fn(obj[key]);

    return obj[key];
}
```